# Run python script on node-webkit startup (nw.js)

Tags: python, desktop-application, node-webkit, nw.js

I have a Python-based app that controls LEDs. It uses `Flask` to create a webserver so I can work with a nice UI using HTML, CSS, and JS.

My current process:

1. `python home.py`
2. navigate to `localhost:5000` in browser
3. profit!

I'd like to take it a step further and package it up as a `nw.js` (formerly `node-webkit`) app.

Basically, I believe I simply need to execute my python script before the window loads, so that my tried-and-true flask web server kicks off and creates a `localhost:5000` page for my `nw.js` app interface to open up.

**How can I package my nw.js app so it runs a python script on startup?**

Comment: Simply launch the node-webkit frontend from the python script via `subprocess.Popen`

Answer (score 4):

You can create a loading page and render the actual app after the web server has started.

package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "pythonApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "loading.html",
  "window": {
    "title": "App Name",
    "width": 800,
    "height": 600,
    "position": "center",
  }
}
```

The loading page (loading.html) will load a js file that launches your actual application page as a hidden window and you can then show it when the server is running.

loading.html:

```js
var gui = require('nw.gui');

var currentWindow = gui.Window.get(); // Get reference to loading.html

var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
exec('home.py', {cwd:'.'}, function (error, stdout, stderr){ // Runs your python code
  var appWindow = gui.Window.open('app.html', // Starts your application
    { width: 800,
      height: 600,
      position: 'center',
      focus: false,
      transparent: true // This hides the application window
    }
);
appWindow.on('loaded', function() { // Waits for application to be loaded
  currentWindow.close({force: 'true'}); // Closes loading.html
    appWindow.show();  // Shows app.html
    appWindow.focus(); // Set the focus on app.html
  });
});
```

Anyway that is the gist of it, but you may need to make changes for your particular setup. Hope it helps.

Comment: This loads the app windows, but doesn't seem to run the python script. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use node's [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module, and call that from index.html.

Something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var child_process= require('child_process');
      child_process.spawn('python home.py');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(Code not tested, example only)